# AJAX on success return HTML files instead the data value?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I have this simple `AJAX` code to get the `User Timezone` whenever he is successfully login to the dashboard.

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    'use strict';
    /**
     * Getting user current timezone offset
     */
    var timezone_offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();

    timezone_offset = timezone_offset == 0 ? 0 : -timezone_offset;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url('dashboard'); ?>",
        data: {"timezone": timezone_offset},
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log('error');
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $data = $this->global_data->logged_user();
    $data['page_title']     = 'Dashboard';
    $data['page_directory'] = 'pages/dashboard';
    $data['greeting']       = $this->global_helpers->greeting() . ' !';

    $chart_data = array();
    $order_history = $this->trade_history->chart_data();
    foreach($order_history AS $d)
    {
        $chart_data[] = array(
            'y' => $this->global_helpers->month_name($d->month) ."' ". $d->year,
            'a' => $d->profit,
            'b' => $d->loss
        );
    }

    echo $_POST['timezone'];

    $data['chart_data'] = json_encode($chart_data);
    $this->load->view('template', $data);
}
```

But the problem is, when it's success why it's return the HTML header? not the data I wish to get?

[image]

What do I do wrong here? And I put this `AJAX` code in `footer.php` file. Sorry for this silly question but I just got stuck here.

I appreciated any kind of helps, Thanks!

**Edited**

Sorry for this silly post, I can't use that way, i just need to create another controller for handling any kind of `AJAX` value, so the problem will be fixed.

Comment: Try to set `"dataType : json"` in ajax query

Comment: @YuraRosiak Nah sorry, it was my mistake from the beginning, I sent the data to a view controller not the controller for handling ajax, silly me

Comment: You can use `$this->input->is_ajax_request()` inside `dashboard()` so you know the right output to send client-side.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't render HTML inside an alert anyway.

I see that you ended up solving this issue, but, FYI, if you ever need a controller to return HTML as data, use the third parameter on view method:

`echo $this->load->view('template', $data, TRUE);`

[See more at Codeigniter docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#returning-views-as-data) :)